# Jquery Selector always return 0 for Object

Tags: jquery, visualforce

I am using this

```
alert($j(':checkbox').length);
```

and my page has input element as:

```
<input id="pageId:formIds:refOut:pdsectionId:pbtable:1:check1" type="checkbox" name="pageId:formIds:refOut:pdsectionId:pbtable:1:check1" class="foo">
```

still the length is return as zero.

Note the Jquery Lib is loading with no error.

Full Code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($j('input:checkbox').length);
</script>
```

Comment: May we know the reason for the need of noconflict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the tag to the selector to work with the `:checkbox` psuedo selector:

```
alert($j('input:checkbox').length);
```

Note this will require you to have mapped jQuery to `$j` otherwise use:

```
alert($('input:checkbox').length);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cUAWw/

Since the fiddles seem to work but posted code does not, the element may not be available when the script loads. Try adding:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($('input:checkbox').length);
});
```

Comment: This is just better for performance point of view but both selectors have same behaviour, find all checkboxes

Comment: `$(':checkbox').length` works just as well! No real need to specify the tag name with the selector. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/qvW9L/

Comment: @user614946 I added a working fiddle, which makes me suspect jquery is not loading.

Answer (score 4):

You have to wait for DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
    alert($j(':checkbox').length); //FYI prefixed with element type is preferred: $j('input:checkbox')
});
```

Or set your code just before body closing tag:

```
<script>
   /*....*/
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This I believe is the actual reason.

Comment: @techfoobar easier once OP edited question with more relevant info ;)